# (Why) is row rank the dimension of the space $V$ minus the dimension of the kernel of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I saw the following proof for row rank = column rank using rank nullity:

From rank nullity theorem: $\dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\text{Im}(f)) = \dim(V)$.
$\dim(\text{Im}(f)) = \dim(V) - \dim(\ker(f))$.

By definition, the dimension of the image of $f$ is the column rank.
Similarly, by definition, the row rank is given by the difference between the dimension of the space $V$ and the dimension of the kernel of $f$.

Thus, column rank = row rank. I get why $\dim(\text{Im}(f)) =$ column rank but not why $\dim(V) - \dim(\ker(f)) =$ row rank.

Why (if at all) is the definition of row rank as the number of linearly independent rows in the matrix equivalent to dim(V) - dim(ker(f))?

Comment: Sorry, poor wording. What I'm asking is why (if at all) the definition of row rank as the number of linearly independent rows in the matrix is equivalent to dim(V) - dim(ker(f)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's because the row space (span of the row vectors) is orthogonal to the nullspace.**

To see why, let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ be a matrix and let $\text{Im}(A^T)$ denote the row space. If $x \in \ker(A)$, we have that
$$Ax = 0 \implies a_1\cdot x = \cdots = a_m\cdot x = 0$$
where $a_i$ is a row vector of $A$. This implies that $\text{Im}(A^T) = \ker(A)^\perp$. Since $\ker(A)$ is a subspace, we have
$$\dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\ker(A)^\perp) = \dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\text{Im}(A^T)) = n $$
and so
$$\dim(\text{Im}(A^T)) = n - \dim(\ker(A)).$$